# Send MySql result in res.send

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm kind of newbie to the node.js, this might be silly one but not actually getting proper way to achieve this. here I'm trying to send the mysql result from the node.js res.send() method, here below I'm adding my code.

```
router.post('/get_doc_msgs', (req, res)=>{
 var d_msg = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE d_id = ?";
var d_msgs = [req.body.doc_id_msgs];
  db.query(d_msg, d_msgs, (err,rows) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('error ', err);
      }
    else{ 
      res.send(rows)
      }
  });
})
```

and here is my function to get the data to the rendered ejs file.

```
function getmsgs(){
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: '/get_doc_msgs',
  data: {
    doc_id_msgs : $('#doct_id').val();
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('#msg_q').html(data);
  }
})
```

}

advance thank you for help and suggestions .

Comment: Whats the issue ? and why are you using ajax ? you can simply use a function to

Comment: What's received in success function

Comment: hi @DezzH . i have data stored in database and i want to fetch that and show in the rendered ejs page, can u please show how can i do that by code,

Comment: hi @Sagar tried by checking console.log didn't got any response. its blank

Comment: try to check rows data in node.js

Comment: the console i'm making in server file i'm getting the array but i need to pass that to my ejs file where i can show it in browser

Comment: If it's showing as an array same should be in success function. Try res.json(rows)

Comment: Thank you sagar your replay made me to think about json, i made something like this  res.send({rows:rows}); and got value in my ajax response. thank you for help

Comment: Great Should Add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example of how this might work, I've added server and client code.

If you run

```
node app.js
```

Then go to http://localhost:3000 you should see the example working.

The main issue I believe is you need to use a body-parser in Express so you can parse uploaded data correctly. In this case I've used JSON, you could use another encoding if you wished.

The only change I made to the server code was really to add the body parser.

On the client side, I set a content-type header and used JSON.stringify() on the uploaded data.

It's not a silly question, getting all this stuff to play nice takes a little bit of practice and effort!

**app.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = app;
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Add the credentials to access your database
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : '<user>', /* replace these with real values. */
    password : '<pw>', /* replace these with real values. */
    database : '<db>' /* replace these with real values. */
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("./"));

router.post('/get_doc_msgs', (req, res)=>{
var d_msg = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE d_id = ?";
var d_msgs = [req.body.doc_id_msgs];
    db.query(d_msg, d_msgs, (err,rows) => {
        if(err){
            console.log('error ', err);
        } else { 
            res.send(rows)
        }
    });
})

app.listen(port);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding:20px">
        <label>Doc id:</label><input id="doct_id" value="1"/>
        <h4>Response:</h4>
        <p id="msg_q"></p>
        <script>
            function getmsgs()  {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/get_doc_msgs',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        doc_id_msgs : $('#doct_id').val()
                    }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        for(row of data) {
                            $('#msg_q').append("<li>" + Object.values(row).join("\t") + "</li>");
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log("Doc id:", $('#doct_id').val());
            getmsgs();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hie @Terry thank you very much for ur complete code. and thank you once again for iteration of data in ajax that solved my complete issue.

Comment: @prasanna Thank you for testing my answer, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
`getDocMessg = (req, res, next) => {
  mess_id = req.body.doc_id_msgs
db.execute("SELECT* FROM msgs WHERE d_id = ?", [mess_id]).then((results) => {
res to render the page you want to send the data to
res.render('name of page', {
  message : results[0]
})
})
}`
```

something like that should do the job you need to adapt it to your website structure, using ejs you can call the variable message and show it on your page :)

Comment: the code isnt clean but i hope you get the jeez of it :), but before any rendering on your web page you need to console log to see if your query worked, if its it returns an empty variable something is wrong with your call or databse

Comment: hey @DezzH the the page is already rendered. i need to add data to the already rendered ejs file. anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: if you r using ejs my method is a perfect way of sending to your page the data you want to show

Comment: yes @DazzH your method is perfect but in my condition i'm rendering my /index page before only, in that i need to show the msgs as they stored in DB. it's something like a social media, you get login first after if any new msgs comes u get notification of that. something similar to that.